# Windows Phone 8.1 Reload/Refresh a page in Localisation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I am working on localisation. I have a listbox. If i change a language in listbox. The whole application has to be changed to that language(Including the current page).

So i obtained that language from listbox and assigned to

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cul;
```

Question 1: I want to reload/refresh the current page(Ex : Page1)?

```
private void LocList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cul;
    var resourceContext = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
    resourceContext.Reset();
}
```

This is not working. I also tried

```
private void LocList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = cul;
    var manager = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current;
    manager.DefaultContext.QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;
}

private void QualifierValues_MapChanged(IObservableMap<string, string> sender, IMapChangedEventArgs<string> @event)
{
    ResourceContext.ResetGlobalQualifierValues(); 
    //ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.Reset();
}
```

Question 2 : If i navigate from Page1 to Page2, the changed language is applied in page2. But if i come back to Page1, The language change is not applied.

Question 2 (Continuation) : I mean If i Navigate from Page2 to Page1. The Page1 constructor is not hitting (If the constructor is hitted the Page initialization will happen to get correct output).

Guide me if i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you People. i got output. 
The Issue is, the cache was set to Required. Now to fix it i disabled the cache

```
  this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

Previously it was NavigationCacheMode.Required.
This is the fix for Question 2

Now For Question 1: This code made my page to refresh

```
 var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        _Frame.Navigate(_Frame.Content.GetType());
        _Frame.GoBack(); // remove from BackStack
```

Comment: In 1 post i found                                                                        public bool Reload() { return Reload(null); }
private bool Reload(object param)
{
    Type type = this.Frame.CurrentSourcePageType;
    if (this.Frame.BackStack.Any())
    {
        type = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().SourcePageType;
        param = this.Frame.BackStack.Last().Parameter;
    }
    try { return this.Frame.Navigate(type, param); }
    finally { this.Frame.BackStack.Remove(this.Frame.BackStack.Last()); }
} Piece of code. this i got error (ie) **Last()** and **Any()** was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 1 Try to change event type to SelectionChanged on your Listbox i.e from LocList_SelectedIndexChanged to LocList_SelectionChanged.

Ad. 2 Not sure but which version of WP8.1 do you use(silverlight?/win-rt?), navigation is different on both.  But as a fast suggestion (suppose win-rt version) don't use GoBack() method, but try to reload language not in constructor but in OnNavigatedTo() method.

Anyway try to give more code.

Best of luck.

Comment: I am using Win-rt. 1 doubt. If i did not use GoBack(). I am getting 1 issue.  Now I am Going from Page1->Page2. Change the language(SO page is refreshed here). now i want to do Page2->Page1. Here According to stack The Page2 will be redirected again instead of Page1